# change permissions for all script on remote servers using ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to update permissions on all the shell script in a particular directory on remote servers using ansible but it gives me error:

```
- name: update permissions
  file: dest=/home/goldy/scripts/*.sh mode=a+x
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
fatal: [machineA]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "file (/home/goldy/scripts/*.sh) is absent, cannot continue", "path": "/home/goldy/scripts/*.sh", "state": "absent"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/copy/copy.retry
```

What wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run a task with find module to collect all .sh files on that directory, and register the results in a variable.
then run a 2nd task with the file module that will update the permissions when file's extension ends in .sh.

check sample playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
  tasks:
    - name: parse /tmp directory
      find:
        paths: /tmp
        patterns: '*.sh'
      register: list_of_files

    - debug:
        var: item.path
      with_items: "{{ list_of_files.files }}"

    - name: change permissions
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        mode: a+x
      with_items: "{{ list_of_files.files }}"
```

Comment: 2nd way, would be to use the `shell` module and run a shell command. whatever suits you best!

Comment: what's the problem with the way I have? why it is complaining?

Comment: if you check the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) of this module, the `dest`/`path` parameter has to be the exact path. doesnt support the wild character that a shell command would. if you want to do it quick and dirty in 1 task, try the `shell` module, to execute a shell command that could take the `*.sh`